# Why my Battery status color in the menubar is Red while it is charged more than 20%?

Tags: macos, battery, charging, menu-bar

I left my MacBook Pro 13-inch, Early 2011 running OS X 10.11.6 for half an hour while was charged more than 50%, and when I came back, I saw the Battery status color in the menubar is red while it was at 51%.

My laptop warned me 2 years ago about "Service Battery" but this color misbehavior has not happened before.

Why is the status icon in red color while it is not under 20%?

[image]

Contents of the Battery status:

[image]

Comment: There's a problem with your battery or the charging circuitry.  However, given the age of your MBP, it's most likely the battery (5, going on 6 years old).  They are [cheap](https://goo.gl/zB1RJs) and easy to replace; just remove the bottom screws and you have access to the battery.  ***But...what exactly is your question?***

Comment: @Allan Thanks, I should ask my question in the body instead of the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This malfunction is most likely the case due to the fact that the battery is no longer functioning properly, it can no longer hold a full charge nor charge properly. This means that its possible shows in red because it is at half of whatever the reduced battery life is (that could be anywhere from 50%, or even 70% cut down from the original battery life).

I *highly* recommend you go to an Apple tech support employee at one of Apple's stores. You will have to wait a bit for help, but I have a strong feeling that they will tell you the computer needs a new battery.